# How do you populate values into a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, oop

I have a code that works for merging 2 linked lists for leetcode. However, upon testing it, I am facing a bottleneck. How do I populate the ListNode with a list? the following outputs just 1 whatever, not the merged linked list.

```
from typing import Optional

class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:

        place_holder = ListNode()
        tmp = place_holder

        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                tmp.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                tmp.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            tmp = tmp.next

        if list1 is None:
            tmp.next = list2

        if list2 is None:
            tmp.next = list1

        return place_holder.next

#input the two integer lists
l1 = [1, 2, 4]
l2 = [1, 3, 4]

list1 = ListNode(l1[0])
list2 = ListNode(l2[0])

list_result = Solution().mergeTwoLists(list1, list2)
print(list_result)
```

Comment: You need a way to convert a regular Python list to a linked list. Your nodes are initialized with one integer each (never mind that it came from `l1` and `l2`), so they can't grow any next elements by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `__str__` so it prints the whole linked list:

```
    def __str__(self):
        s = f"({str(self.val)})"
        if self.next:
            s += f" -> {self.next}"  # be careful not to build any circular lists...
        return s
```

and now you can see the actual result of your merge function:

```
(1) -> (1)
```

which is 100% correct (at least for these inputs) because you merged the lists `(1)` and `(1)`.

Writing a function that lets you turn a list of multiple numbers into a single linked list will make it easier to test this logic with longer inputs.  One option would be to just do this in your `ListNode` constructor:

```
from typing import List, Optional, Union

class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val: int = 0, *vals: int) -> None:
        self.val = val
        self.next = ListNode(*vals) if vals else None

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        s = f"({str(self.val)})"
        if self.next:
            s += f" -> {self.next}"
        return s
```

Now you can do:

```
list1 = ListNode(1, 2, 4)
list2 = ListNode(1, 3, 4)

list_result = Solution().mergeTwoLists(list1, list2)
print(list_result)  # (1) -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to convert a regular Python list to a linked list. Your nodes are initialized with one integer each (never mind that it came from l1 and l2), so they can't grow any next elements by themselves. To fix it, add a static method to ListNode that accepts a list:

```
class ListNode:

    @static
    def fromList(lst):
        if not lst:
            return None

        return ListNode(lst[0], next=ListNode.fromList(lst[1:]))
```

This will recursively convert a Python list into a linked list. Then you can initialize your linked lists like this:

```
list1 = ListNode.fromList(l1)
list2 = (same)
```

Comment: Why static? Make it a class method and return `cls(...)`. (But the `next` argument must *also* be a `ListNode` instance, not the rest of the argument list.)

Comment: re the `next` argument, yeah that's what I meant... it was fixed already thanks

Comment: You'll also need to handle an empty `lst` argument (which the recursion will eventually produce).

Comment: Sigh, yeah you're right... Should have known better than think I can write recursion code off the top of my head. Thanks.

Comment: But IMHO this is not a good use case for a class method. The class will not be extended, this is not a good time to introduce the OP to this kind of abstraction, and Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: There's no downside to being *ready* for inheritance, though. Your making it seem like static methods are commonly used in Python; they really aren't. Alternate constructors like this are the primary use case for class methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `list` value into a `List` value. (I recommend using separate classes for nodes and the list that consists of those nodes.)

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)


class List:
    def __init__(self, values=None):
        # Dummy node that is independent of any actual
        # data. You can store the length (or really, any
        # metadata you like) in the dummy node.
        self.head = ListNode(0)
        if values is None:
            values = []

        for x in values:
            self.append(x)

    def append(self, value):
         ...


list1 = List(l1)
list2 = List(l2)
```

You'll need to implement `List.append`, and possibly some other methods. It's better to do all the pointer wrangling in `List` itself and to provide methods for `mergeTwoLists` to construct the resulting `List`.